# separate comma strings in parameter and save in table SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a parameter with comma in it.
Like `@parameter = 'abc,xyz,fgh'`
I want to separate it like:

```
column1     column2
1           abc
1           xyz
1           fgh
```

I have a trigger which is receiving a parameter named **@PackageCode** with comma values. Now I want to separate its value and save it in table.

Below is the SQLtrigger code I've tried so far.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CustomerPackageSplit ON BM_CustomerInfo
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @CustNIC int;
    declare @CustID varchar(100);
    declare @CustName decimal(10,2);
    declare @PackageCode varchar(100);

SELECT @CustNIC = i.CustNIC from inserted i;
SELECT @CustID = i.CustID from inserted i;
SELECT @CustName = i.CustName from inserted i;
SELECT @PackageCode = i.Package from inserted i;


INSERT INTO BM_CustPackage (CustNIC,CustID,CustName,PackageCode)
VALUES (@CustNIC,@CustID,@CustName,@PackageCode)

GO
```

Comment: You should really do the split before inserting the data into the table. The trigger also has a serious fault, inserted (and deleted) can contain more than one row.

Comment: Isn't there any method to do it from sql?

Answer (score 1):

In **SQL Server 2016** you can use `string_split` function (more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt684588.aspx)).

Here is a simple query that splits your comma separated values:

```
declare @parameter   varchar(100)

set @parameter = 'abc,xyz,fgh'

select 1 as column1, [value] as column2 
from string_split(@parameter, ',')
```

The output of this command is:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╗
║ column1 ║ column2 ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║       1 ║ abc     ║
║       1 ║ xyz     ║
║       1 ║ fgh     ║
╚═════════╩═════════╝
```

For older SQL Server version you can find many custom implementations of split functions, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x) or [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/).